# Rails, how to stop it removing items from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an app which allows users to add shows to their account. To do this I have a User, show and user_show models and associate them as follows:

```
# User.rb:
has_many: user_show
has_many: shows, through: :user_shows

# Show.rb
has_many :user_shows
has_many :users, through: :user_shows

# User_show.rb
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: show
```

currently in my user controller i have this for adding and removing:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def add_show
    show = Show.find params[:id]
    current_user.shows << show
    redirect_to my_shows_path
    flash[:notice] = "Show added"
  end

  def remove_show
    show = Show.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to my_shows_path
    flash[:notice] = "Show removed"
  end
end
```

and my routes like this:

```
resources :users, except: :show do
  collection do
    get "add_show/:id", action: :add_show, as: "add_show"
    delete "remove_show/:id", action: :remove_show, as: "remove_show" #-> should create /users/add_show, considering you have current_user
  end
end
```

As you can probably see, it completely deletes the show from the database and doesn't just remove it from that user. How would I change this to avoid this from occurring?

Comment: `User.rb:    has_many: user_show`s - this type i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a has_many through relationship, the easiest way to destroy the relationship, but not the actual endpoints, would be:

```
 current_user.user_shows.find_by(:show_id => params[:id]).destroy
```

So Essentially, find the link in the join table, and destroy that.

Comment: UserShow.where(show_id: params[:id],user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy  --- Better syntax

Comment: @matanco I think current_user.user_shows is nicer, it's more readable I think, and using find_by is more concise than using `where(..).first`

Comment: @matanco - Using `UserShow` class directly allows user to remove somebody's else relation, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @HarryLucas Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

You are destroying the `Show`, not the relation between a `User` and a `Show` (`UserShow`). Try something like this:

```
def remove_show
    current_user.user_shows.where(show: params[:id]).destroy_all
    redirect_to my_shows_path
    flash[:notice] = "Show removed"
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `find_by` or `destroy_all`? There is no destroy on relation which takes no param.

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes probably so, fixed it.

Comment: yea the first time I tried it i got an error of invalid number of arguments 0 for 1?